# Run Multiple Tasks (Variable Number) in parallel and continue when all have finished

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

I need to start a "number" of tasks (variable but less than 10) not in parallel,
    and wait for them all to finish, getting from each the result.
    I'm getting the result from each of them, saving in a list and then using it in the end.

Here's my code, and it's working but I think there gotta be a cleaner way to do that.

**CAUSING THE NUMBER OF TASKS**

```
List<String> Arguments = new List<String> { "AA", "BB", "CC" }; 

List<String> ResultList = new List<String>();  

//**AT LEAST I'VE GOT ONE**

Task<String> Tasks = Task<String>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    return DoSomething(Arguments[0]);
});

ResultList.Add(Tasks.Result);

for (Int32 i = 1; i < Arguments.Count; i++)
{
    ResultList.Add(Tasks.ContinueWith<String>(Result =>
    {
        return DoSomething(Arguments[i]);

    }).Result);
}

//**DO I NEED THIS?? It's working even without!!**
//Tasks.Wait();

for (Int32 i = 0; i < ResultList.Count; i++)
{
    textBox1.AppendText(ResultList[i] + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need more than one task? Why do you need a task at all when all you are doing is **synchronously** waiting for it to complete.

Comment: you can use async await

Comment: `Tasks.Result` won't compile.

Comment: If you don't want them in parallel it's not multithreading. If you just want non-ui-blocking, that's asynchronous. You don't need continuation because you're not passing the arguments from one task to the next.

Comment: Tasks.Result won't compile -> Yes it works (have you tried it?)

Comment: Thanks I would have done surely in a different way but I'm calling a web api (Not mine) that doesn't allow me multiple call in parallet, that's why I need to wait for each task to finish.

Comment: @user3103198 If you're calling WebAPI, you don't need threadpool threads at all. HTTP calls are asynchronous by nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need the `Wait()` call. Documentation for [Task<T>.Result](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) states:

> Accessing the property's get accessor blocks the calling thread until the asynchronous operation is complete; it is equivalent to calling the Wait method.

Answer (score 5):

I think this is what you are attempting to do : ie start a whole load of parallel tasks and wait for them all to complete before proceeding

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace UnitTestProject2
{
    class Class4
    {
        public void run()
        {
            List<String> Arguments = new List<String> { "AA", "BB", "CC" };
            List<Task<String>> tasks = new List<Task<string>>();

            foreach (string arg in Arguments)
            {
                    tasks.Add(
                        this.DoSomething(arg)
                        .ContinueWith(t => this.DoSomething(t.Result))
                        .Unwrap<string>()
                    );
            }

            Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

            foreach(Task<string> t in tasks)
            {
                textBox1 += (t.Result + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
            }

        }

        public async Task<string> DoSomething(string arg)
        {
            return arg;
        }

        public string textBox1;
    }
}
```

Comment: `.Result` can raise an `AggregateException`

Comment: you mean in the lambda? I must admit I normaly would continuewith a method and pass in the task so you can handle non completion but msdn has example with the result lambda and it is more consise for examples. also means you can use the same method twice in the case

Answer (score 0):

you can use async await

```
public async List<String> SomeMethod() {
   List<String> Arguments = new List<String> { "AA", "BB", "CC" }; 
   List<String> ResultList = new List<String>();  
   foreach(var argument in Arguments) 
   {
     var result = await DoSomething(argument);
     ResultList.Add(result);
   }
   return ResultList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your entire code, as of now, runs synchronously. You're creating a `Task` then actively blocking on it, using `Task.Result`.

If you truly understand what parallelism is about, and you really need to execute as many tasks as you have arguments in your list, then you can offload all of them and then asynchronously wait (this is the *key*, being *asynchronous*) as they complete:

```
var arguments = new[] { "A", "B", "C" };
var tasks = arguments.Select(argument => Task.Run(() => DoSomething(argument))).ToList();

while (tasks.Count > 0)
{
    var finishedTask = await Task.WhenAny(tasks);
    textBox1.AppendText(string.Format("{0}{1}{1}", finishedTask.Result,
                                                   Environment.NewLine));

    tasks.Remove(finishedTask);
}
```

**Edit:**
From your comments:

> I'm calling a web api (Not mine) that doesn't allow me multiple call
>   in parallel, that's why I need to wait for each task to finish

Then you don't need a thread for each argument at all. Two things:

1. You can make the call entirely synchronous, as you have to wait for the completion of each call. Using threadpool threads for that is merely useless
2. You can make asynchronous calls without needing to use threads at all. Look into `HttpClient` and its `XXXAsync` methods (such as `GetAsync`).